# Adding a blocking factor in stat_poly_eq()

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpmisc

I'm fixing a linear regression with lm() like

```
model<-lm(y~x+a, data=dat)
```

where a is a blocking variable with multiple factor levels.

```
summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = dat)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.45006 -0.20737  0.04593  0.26337  0.91628 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     -7.704042   1.088024  -7.081 1.08e-10 ***
x     0.248889   0.036436   6.831 3.81e-10 ***
a1   0.002695   0.150530   0.018  0.98575    
a2   0.491749   0.152378   3.227  0.00162 ** 
a3   0.349772   0.145024   2.412  0.01740 *  
a4  -0.009058   0.138717  -0.065  0.94805    
a5  0.428085   0.128041   3.343  0.00111 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4505 on 119 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4228,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3937 
F-statistic: 14.53 on 6 and 119 DF,  p-value: 2.19e-12
```

I'm trying to display the same equation and R2 I would get with summary(model) when plotting the raw data and the regression line using ggplot, but because I'm not actually providing a, it's not taking into the fitting of stat_poly_eq()

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(slope=coef(model)[2], intercept=coef(model)[1], color='red') +
  stat_poly_eq(data=plankton.dat, formula = y ~ x,  
           aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
           parse = TRUE, size=3, colour= "red")
```

[image: ggplot]

Naturally, because lm() and stat_poly_eq() fit the model differently, the resulting parameter estimates and R2 are different.

Is it possible to include the blocking variable in stat_poly_eq and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Having factor `a` six levels, you have fitted six parallel lines, so it does not make much sense to show only one line and one equation. If factor `a` describes blocks, then using `lme()` to fit a mixed effects model is possible, and it will give you only one estimate for the line. You have to consider the *contrasts* used by default in R, and that the first level of `a` or `a0` is the "reference", so the line plotted in your example is for block level `a0` and is not valid for the dataset as a whole.

`stat_poly_eq()` supports only `lm()`. `stat_poly_eq()` works in the same way as `stat_smooth(method = "lm")` as it is intended to be used together with it. If you are fitting the model outside of ggplot then you will need to build a suitable label manually using plotmath syntax, and add it in an annotation layer using `annotate(geom = "text", x = 27, y = 1, label = "<your string>", parse = TRUE)`. To create the string that I show with the placeholder `<your string>`, you can extract the coefficient estimates in a similar way as you do in `geom_abline()` in your plot example, and use `paste()` or `sprintf()` to assemble the equation. You can also use `coef()` with a model fitted with `lme()`.

Other statistics in package 'ggpmisc' let you fit a model with `lme()` but you would anyway need to assemble the label manually. If you will be producing many plots, you may find it worthwhile cheking the [User Guide of package 'ggpmisc'](https://docs.r4photobiology.info/ggpmisc/articles/model-based-annotations.html) for the details.